# Laravel - How to download sample Excel file from the storage

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have Excel Import project using Maatwebsite package in Laravel-5.8. I have been able to perform the Excel import and save it into the database successfully.

**UserController**

```
class UserssController extends Controller
{
  public function importExportView()
  {
     return view('import');
  }

  public function import() 
  {
    Excel::import(new UsersImport,request()->file('file'));
    return back();
  }
}
```

**user.blade**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card bg-light mt-3">
        <div class="card-header">
            Import Excel
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{ route('import') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control">
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Import User Data</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, there is one more thing. I have a sample Excel file. Before import, I want the user to download the sample excel sheet and see how the file format is, and how it should be arranged.

The file is in this directory: public/storage/sample/user.xlsx

How do I modify my code, especially in the view to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: @nakov - Yes, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download directly in a route function, you can use the `response()->download()` method directly in the return statement.

There is a small example of file download with this method

```php
/**
 * Download file with "response()->download()" method
 * @param Request $request
 * @param String  $filename containing filename and extension (.xls in this example)
 * @return BinaryFileResponse
 */
public function downloadAction(Request $request, $pathHash, $filename) {
    // Get path from storage directory
    $path = storage_path('app/' . $filename);

    // Download file with custom headers
    return response()->download($path, $filename, [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $filename . '"'
    ]);
}
```

This method is useful for all files not available in `public/storage` directory.

You can change the `Content-Type` header value by the corresponding mime type of the file. There is a table of common file extensions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Answer (score 1):

There is a `download` method in the `storage` class may help you

```
Storage::download('file.jpg');
```

you can check more in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#downloading-files)